# Доступ на сервер

Tags: ip, shell, proxy, linux

Есть данные от shella. Легально полученные.
Но я должен логинится туда только с определенного IP.
Собственно на том IP настроена http прокси, к которой у меня есть доступ.
Как логинится к серверу, чтобы IP был как у http прокси?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кратко, то зайти в шелл через http-прокси невозможно.

Comment: Черт.
Я угробил свой собственный VDS.
Придется писать хостеру, чтобы снес его.